# How to print a dynamic variable?

Tags: python, loops, class, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm new in Python and I have a problem: in the package that I'm using, there is a command that I can recall in the following way: example.D1, example.D2, changing the number that follows D.
I want to create a loop for to print all results with the number, following D, from 1 to 100.

I have tried with

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print(example.Di)
```

and the error is `raise AttributeError("'*' has no attribute '%s'" % name) AttributeError: '*' has no attribute 'Di'`

How can I return this command "loopable"?

I hope my description is clear,
thanks

Comment: `print(getattr(example, f"D{i}"))`, could work.

Comment: You could accept the answer which helped you most and also upvote all helpful answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `eval` (not recommended), access the local variables with `locals()` (depends on the context), or preferable use the `getattr` method to access the class instance variables of `example`:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print(getattr(example, 'D{0}'.format(i)))
```

If you want to return a specific value if `Di` does not exist, you can add this as a default return value to `getattr`, f.i. return the string `'variable Di not found'`.

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print(getattr(example, 'D{0}'.format(i), 'variable D{0} not found'.format(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print out your object (class instance) state/attributes in so many ways, one of them is the builtin `getattr`

```
def get_attributes_of_object(obj):
  for attr in dir(obj):
    print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
```

**using the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) module**

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get
> information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods,
> functions, tracebacks..

use the method below:

> `inspect.getmembers(object[, predicate])`
>
> Return all the members of an object in a list of (name, value) pairs
> sorted by name. If the optional predicate argument....

```
name_value_pairs_list = inspect.getmembers(Di)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **f-strings** which is an improved way of using **str.format()**

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print(getattr(example, f'D{i}'))
```